# GridBagLayout: How to set fixed column width?

Tags: java, swing, awt, gridbaglayout

I've been trying to set fixed column width in the following code for ages...The thing is that when I add a label to the panel on the left, then the width is incremented automatically...and i Would like the column width to be fixed...

Could anyone help me please??

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CurrentItem extends JPanel{

    private static JFrame currentScreen; 

    public CurrentItem(JFrame p) { 

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Borramos todo lo que haya en la pantalla 
        this.removeAll();
        this.revalidate();

        currentScreen = p;     

        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);      

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());  

        currentScreen.add(this);       

        // --->
        Panel leftPanel = new Panel(); 
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        c.weightx = 1.5;
        c.weighty = 1;
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;      
        this.add(leftPanel, c);
        // <---

        // --->
        Panel secondPanel = new Panel(); 
        secondPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        this.add(secondPanel, c);
        // <---     

        // --->
        Panel rightPanel = new Panel(); 
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        c.weightx = 1.5;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        this.add(rightPanel, c);
        // <---

        currentScreen.setVisible(true);

        this.requestFocusInWindow();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Panel`, that is an AWT component. Use `JPanel` which is the Swing component.

Comment: Instead of adding these huge `import` statements, you should've added one `main` method, for someone to try it with

Answer (score 10):

`GridBagLayout` places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and then uses the components' *preferred sizes* to determine how big the cells should be.

Weights are used to determine how to distribute space among columns (`weightx`) and among rows (`weighty`); this is important for specifying resizing behavior.

Generally weights are specified with 0.0 and 1.0 as the extremes: the numbers in between are used as necessary.

Read more [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

---

Sample code: (below code set fixed width column with 100% vertical size.)

```
Panel leftPanel = new Panel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(..., ...);
    }
};
```

Remove `weightx` for first column and override `getPreferredSize()` method.

```
leftPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
this.add(leftPanel, c);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know ahead of time the labels that you'll be adding, and how wide each one is:

- You can call `label.getPreferredSize().width` on each label to determine the width of the largest label.
- Then, add an invisible component (`Box.createHorizontalStrut(width)`) to the column to force it to be that wide at all times.
- Then, when you add all of your labels, the width of that column of the panel will not change.